# mac hadoop compile 'linux/loop.h' file not found

Tags: macos, hadoop, compiler-errors

When I try to compile Hadoop on Mac, I got some fatal errors like below.

`/Users/xxx/Documents/software/hadoop/hadoop-yarn-project/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-server/hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager/src/main/native/container-executor/impl/runc/runc.c:18:10: fatal error: 'linux/loop.h' file not found [WARNING] #include <linux/loop.h> [WARNING] /Users/xxx/Documents/software/hadoop/hadoop-yarn-project/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-server/hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager/src/main/native/container-executor/impl/runc/runc_reap.c:24:10: fatal error: 'mntent.h' file not found [WARNING] #include <mntent.h> [WARNING] /Users/xxx/Documents/software/hadoop/hadoop-yarn-project/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-server/hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager/src/main/native/container-executor/impl/container-executor.c:1680:5: error: implicit declaration of function 'ioctl' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]`
It shows 'linux/loop.h' and 'mntent.h' not found, so How can solve it?

Comment: You must show all your build options.

Answer (score 1):

This work for me, just refer to the answer on this post [Compile hadoop native libraries in Mac OS Catalina. error: unknown type name 'constexpr'. alias declarations are a C++11 extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63008344/compile-hadoop-native-libraries-in-mac-os-catalina-error-unknown-type-name-co)

```
export CC=$(which gcc-10)
export CXX=$(which g++-10)
export CPP=$(which cpp-10)
export LD=$(which gcc-10)
```